# queryOrdered doesn't always return data on tableViewCell in correct order

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database, notifications, timestamp

I am trying to order data on the notifications page from new to old based on timestamp, right now - when i run it, sometimes it is in the correct order but other times it is random and incorrect. Please let me know if there is anything i can add to make sure it runs smoothly at all times, thank you in advance :)

My firebase JSON structure is:

```
"notifications" : {
  "BlP58dSQGCUBwhst91yha43AQu42" : {
    "-LeNCQJ6nUSR1263iKyj" : {
      "from" : "FRuuk20CHrhNlYIBmgN4TTz3Cxn1",
      "timestamp" : 1557331817,
      "type" : "true"
    },
    "-LeNCRwNpNaXm2qhYPpu" : {
      "from" : "FRuuk20CHrhNlYIBmgN4TTz3Cxn1",
      "timestamp" : 1557331824,
      "type" : "true"
    },
    "BlP58dSQGCUBwhst91yha43AQu42-FRuuk20CHrhNlYIBmgN4TTz3Cxn1" : {
      "from" : "FRuuk20CHrhNlYIBmgN4TTz3Cxn1",
      "timestamp" : 1557331811,
      "type" : "false"
    }
  },
```

My code:

```
func observeNotification(withId  id: String, completion: @escaping (Notifications) -> Void) {
    REF_NOTIFICATION.child(id).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let newNoti = Notifications.transform(dict: dict, key: snapshot.key)
            completion(newNoti)
        }
    })
}
```

Edit:

The function is then called in the NotificationViewController like this:

```
func loadNotifications() {
    guard let currentUser = Api.User.CURRENT_USER else { return }
    Api.Notification.observeNotification(withId: currentUser.uid , completion: { notifications in
        guard let uid = notifications.from else { return }
        self.fetchUser(uid: uid, completed: {
            self.notifications.insert(notifications, at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    })
}
```

and loadNotifications() is called in the viewDidLoad

UPDATE:

Trying to do it using "for child in snapshot.children" but nothing is showing on notifications page anymore

```
func observeNotification(withId  id: String, completion: @escaping (Notifications) -> Void) {
    REF_NOTIFICATION.child(id).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            let notificationOrder = self.REF_NOTIFICATION.child(key).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")

            notificationOrder.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                    print(dict)
                    let newNoti = Notifications.transform(dict: dict, key: snapshot.key)
                    completion(newNoti)
                }
            })
        }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `observeNotification`?

Comment: I have added an edit to show where its called :)

Answer (score 0):

The `DataSnapshot` that you get back from Firebase contains three types of information:

1. The key of each child that matched the query.
2. The value of each child that matched the query.
3. The order in which the children result from the query.

When you convert the entire result to a dictionary (`dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]`), there is only place for the keys and the values. So the order of the children gets lost.

To maintain the order of the child nodes, loop over the query results of `snapshot.children` as shown in the documentation on [listening for lists of data with a `value` event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).

Comment: Hi frank, appreciate your reply. This is new to me so it might be a stupid question but i've added an update in my code to try and follow this method but now nothing is showing on my notifications page - can you tell me what I could be doing wrong?